# PHP Login Form using DashDB

Tags: php, authentication, db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm Trying to create a Login form using PHP with the DashDB service from Bluemix, I really dont know whats wrong with this code and I would really appreciate your help! My code is composed of five parts: ConexionDB.php, checklogin.php, login_success.php, logout.php and main_login.php

**DashDB Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBERS (
  ID         INT NOT NULL,
  USERNAME     VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  PASSWORD       VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL DEFAULT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
 );
```

**ConexionDB.php**

```
<?php
// Parse VCAP
if( getenv("VCAP_SERVICES") ) {
    $json = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
}
// No DB credentials
else {
    throw new Exception("No Database Information Available.", 1);
}

// Decode JSON and gather DB Info
$services_json = json_decode($json,true);
$bludb_config = $services_json["dashDB"][0]["credentials"];

// Create DB connect string
$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
   $bludb_config["db"].
   ";HOSTNAME=".
   $bludb_config["host"].
   ";PORT=".
   $bludb_config["port"].
   ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
   $bludb_config["username"].
   ";PWD=".
   $bludb_config["password"].
   ";";

?>
```

**main_login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Application Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php

//Include DB conexion
require('includes/ConexionDB.php');

$tbl_name="MEMBERS"; // Table name

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// Connect to BLUDB
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
if ($conn) {

    // Prepare, execute SQL and iterate through resultset
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);
    $result = db2_execute($stmt);

//$result=db2_query($sql);

?>

<?php

// DB2_num_row is counting table row
$count=db2_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>


<?php
    db2_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**login_success**

```
// Check if session is not registered, redirect back to main page.
// Put this code in first line of web page.
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

**logout**

```
// Put this code in first line of web page.
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: It would help if you give additional details about what is going wrong.

Comment: you question is not quite enough, add your error if any or which part if the code is not working as per your understanding.

Comment: What is the schema name for the table "MEMBERS"? You should use SCHEMA.TABLENAME in your code if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem is that when I click on login, i am redirected to the checklogin.php page and just shows a blank page, so, I think the checklogin.pho code is not checking the database correctly, it just doesnt do anything.

The schema name would be DASH103758.MEMBERS, I tested it in thay way in the code but I had the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an alternate cloud foundry build pack that contains the db2 client.

If you have not done yet please download Cloud Foundry command line tool and also your PHP application starting code (you can download both from the "Start Coding" link on the right side of your application window in Bluemix UI).

Run "cf login".

Run the following command to push your application with a php buildpack with db2:

```
cf push <app-name> -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php
```

After application is restarted test it again.

You can find more details here:

http://bit.ly/1UROtMO

Answer (score 1):

there are some problems in your code and build :)

1) change

> $tbl_name="MEMBERS";

with

> $tbl_name="SCHEMA.MEMBERS";

where 'SCHEMA' is 'DASH103758' in your case (as suggested by *data_henrik* )

2) you have to push using a custom buildpack cause you want to use db2client(as suggested by *adasilva*). The CF command line are:

> cf login -u yourusername -o yourorganization -s yourspace
>
> cf push YOUAPPNAME -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php
>   -p YOURAPP_LOCAL_PATH

3) the function db2_num_rows( .. ); does not accept a boolean value. You are passing $result that is a boolean. db2_execute, infact, return a boolean (http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-execute.php).

So, I suggest change the query string in '***checklogin.php***':

> $sql="SELECT count(*) FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and
>   password='$mypassword'";

and the check like this:

> // DB2_num_row is counting table row 
>   //$count=db2_num_rows($result);
>
> // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1
>   row
>
> $count = -1; 
>   if ($result) {
>      $rowcount = db2_fetch_array($stmt);
>      $count = $rowcount[0]; 
>   }
>
> if($count==1){ 
>   .... ...

I hope it can be useful

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please describe your errorYou could retrieve your logs using

> cf logs [your app name] (add --recent to retrieve dump of last ones)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the problem is that when I click on login, i am redirected to the checklogin.php page and just shows a blank page, so, I think the checklogin.pho code is not checking the database correctly, it just doesnt do anything.

The schema name would be DASH103758.MEMBERS, I tested it in thay way in the code but I had the same result.

Comment: If you get a blank page very probably you are getting an error on your code. Check for app logs as described above